# google mail merge single email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using the google simple mail merge (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) I have tried and tried but cannot work out a way to email just the last row, rather than emailing for every row when the script is run.

Any help much appreciated!

```
function sendEmails() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 4);

var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

// Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
var objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

// For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
// it to the appropriate person.
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
// Get a row object
var rowData = objects[i];

// Generate a personalized email.
// Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
// the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
var emailSubject = "Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge";

MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText);
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried varying 'dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow(), 4)'   but this returns an empty email.

I have also tried varying 'for (var i = 0; i < objects.lenght; =++i)'

I have also tried creating a new variable for first row and last row, but I cant work out how to combine them into an array correctly.....

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: In case any one is ever interested:

Change:

```
var rowData = objects[i]
```

to:

```
var rowData = objects[objects.length-1];
```

and:

```
for var (i = 0; i < objects,length; ++i) {
```

to just:

```
var i = 0; i < objects,length; ++i;
```

Comment: `objcets.length-1`, really? I think, there's a typo in `objcets`.